# Understanding simple Linux syscall in libc.a

Tags: linux, assembly, x86-64, system-calls

I'm running a **64-bit Debian 4.7.2-5 Linux** system, using **glibc-2.13-1**. While I was searching for the assembly code of some function calls in `libc.a` I came across this:

```
file format elf64-x86-64

Disassembly of section .text:

0000000000000000 <sync>:
   0:   b9 a2 00 00 00        mov    eax,0xa2
   5:   0f 05                 syscall
   7:   48 3d 01 f0 ff ff     cmp    rax,0xfffffffffffff001
   d:   0f 83 00 00 00 00     jae    13 <sync+0x13>
  13:   c3                    ret
```

I'm a bit confused on what this is doing. What is the point of `mov eax,0xa2` and why isn't the `rax` register being used if this is a 64-bit machine (how does syscall know what system call to make)? In short: what do these 5 lines of code do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

0xa2 is the syscall number. The kernel uses it to decide what actual function to perform, since the `syscall` instruction itself does not contain any information.

As for `rax`, it *does* get used. To continue the tradition started in old days, the `eax` is an alias to the low 32 bits of `rax`. However, there is one not very well-known quirk of x64 architecture: [whenever you modify that low 32-bit part, the top 32-bits *get zeroed*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11177137/why-do-x86-64-instructions-on-32-bit-registers-zero-the-upper-part-of-the-full-6). So, in fact `mov eax, 0xa2` is equivalent to `mov rax, 0xa2`, except its encoding is shorter. NASM, or `as -O2`, will even do that optimization for you.

The last three instructions perform the error handling. In case `%rax` is between -1 and -4095, it means the syscall returned an error, for *any* Linux system call. Here's how it looks in the original source:

```
cmpq $-4095, %rax    /* Check %rax for error.  */
jae __syscall_error  /* Branch forward if it failed.  */
ret                  /* Return to caller.  */
```

You see wrong target for the `jae` because you're disassembling a relocatable object, and the relocatable fields have been set to 0 since they will be patched at the final link time.

To see the relocation targets, **add `-r` switch to `objdump` command line**:

```
0000000000000000 <sync>:
   0:   b8 a2 00 00 00          mov    $0xa2,%eax
   5:   0f 05                   syscall 
   7:   48 3d 01 f0 ff ff       cmp    $0xfffffffffffff001,%rax
   d:   0f 83 00 00 00 00       jae    13 <sync+0x13>
                        f: R_X86_64_PC32        __syscall_error-0x4
  13:   c3                      retq
```

You can see that the bytes at offset `f` will be patched so that jump goes to  `__syscall_error`.

Read [https://cs.lmu.edu/~ray/notes/syscalls/](https://cs.lmu.edu/%7Eray/notes/syscalls/) for more info on syscalls.
Also [The Definitive Guide to Linux System Calls](https://blog.packagecloud.io/eng/2016/04/05/the-definitive-guide-to-linux-system-calls/) blog article.

Answer (score 1):

`mov eax,0xa2` is sufficient to set the entire `rax`, because modifying 32-bit general registers such as `eax` zeroes always the top 32 bits of the corresponding 64-bit register (in this case `rax`).

Syscall number `a2` is `sync`, see `/usr/src/linux/usr/include/asm/unistd_64.h` for the list of Linux x86-64 syscalls (replace `/usr/src/linux/` with the directory where you have your Linux source installed).

As a whole, these lines open a file defined already before these instructions, then compare the return value of `syscall` (in `rax`) with `0xfffffffffffff001`, and then there something a bit strange: `0f 83 00 00 00 00` `jae 13` is a conditional jump to the next instruction, that would be reached anyway.

Comment: In normal Linux systems with glibc headers installed, `/usr/include/asm/unistd_64.h` or some equivalent will exist so you can use `#include <asm/unistd.h>` and use `__NR_sync` in user-space C programs.